# Appending to a file while looping in a Bash Script but opening a new file each script execution

Tags: bash

I am looping through a text file and adding matching lines to a text file using `>> FinalCopy.txt`. However, I would like to always open `FinalCopy.txt` as a blank text file every time I execute the script and overwrite it with whatever new data the bash script generates during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a

```
echo "" > "FinalCopy.txt";
```

or

```
cat /dev/null > "FinalCopy.txt";
```

before your loop does its work